Unable to pair bluetooth 2.1 SPP device with recent samsung phones and tablets
We are using a BLE 2.1 device with SPP for serial communication with android tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 3 (SM-T575).
We recently upgraded to the new Galaxy Tab Active 5 (SM-X306B), and the bluetooth device is shown, be pairing fails.
We thought it could be an Android 14 limitation but pairing succeeds with a OnePlus Nord 2T (CPH2399) phone running Android 14. However, it fails with a Samsung A15 (SM-A155F) phone running Android 14.
This leads us to think that Samsung devices running Android 14 can not be paired with bluetooth 2.1 SPP devices.
Does anyone know more about this ? Is our assumption true, or is it something else ? Is there a workaround ?
Thanks,

SPP is Bluetooth classic technology, not a BLE aka Bluetooth Low Energy profile/service. To find the root cause of the problem you are experiencing, you should enable the Bluetooth HCI Snoop Log on your phone. This will probably give you an idea of what's going wrong.

Thanks for your comment. I enabled HCI Snoop Log, then 1. disabled bluetooth, 2. rebooted, 3. enabled bluetooth, 4. tried pairing my device, 5. pairing failed, 6. disabled bluetooth, 7. ran "adb bugreport" to get the btsnoop_hci.log file. I opened it in wireshark but I'm not qualified to understand what I'm seeing. Can you help me ? The file is here : https://nextcloud.mobil-inn.fr/index.php/s/cQTmJzx9bTCjkFi. Tell me if you need more info.
